# Trying to automatically type code into gov. vehicle registration checker and hit enter

Tags: python, html, selenium

I can't figure out which bit of the website HTML code I take for the vehicle reg input section

https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle

This is the code I am using - what do I put in place of the ZZZ?

Also, any advice on how I would write code to then click through the next page - as when you type a reg in it asks you if the car its found is the correct one - it always is.

Then maybe also advise on how I would automatically scrape this data? - Jus like vaguely what packages to look at or something like that

Thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver

def vehicleRegChecker()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle")
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name(ZZZZZZ).send_keys("XXX19XX")
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can use this xpath: `.//div[@class='form-group no-bottom']/fieldset/div/input` to enter the number and to hit continue use `.//button[@class='button']`

Comment: This answers the question for these 2 cases but doesn't help him learn to find it by himself next time.